# Exporting settings from the registry editor

Tags: windows-vista, windows-registry, regedit

My problem is regarding the unwieldy dinosaur that is Windows Vista. I am using old software that I haven't been able to run in newer OS than Vista (actually the compatibility is XP only).

If I change the screen resolution during runtime and forget to restore the resolution to default before exiting, the software will crash the next time I try to launch it.

If I open the registry editor, find the keys for the software and manually change them to their default values, I can start the software. However this is VERY time consuming so I figured that there must be some way to export the keys into some sort of executable file that does that for me.

A quick Google search confirms my intuition. Though the described steps are all a bit too involved and go straight over my head. I am not command-line literate (in DOS, at least) and the "monkey see, monkey do" approach has not worked here.

Is there some way to create an executable file that simply changes Key values in the registry by somehow "saving" the current setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regedit to export the wanted settings to a `.reg` file and then just double click it to import it back.

Just open the desired part of registry, select the key and use File -> Export.

The file format is text, so if you only need some values and not all to go back to default you can just remove those values with a text editor.